# Split listing into multiple sections

Tags: formatting, listings, counters

I have a big listing that I split up into several `lstlisting` environments like so:

```
Some paragraphs describing part 1

\begin{lstlisting}[language=javascript,name={Caption},label={list:Label}]
Code Part 1
\end{lstlisting}

Some paragraphs describing part 2

\begin{lstlisting}[language=javascript,name={Caption},label={list:Label}]
Code Part 2
\end{lstlisting}

...
```

The code needs, in total, about 2 pages, and I put every interesting component in a separate listing so that I can add a description in-between.
This has several consequences:

1. Since I refer to specific lines in my descriptions, the line numbers should continue where they stopped
2. Since all listing-environments show the same piece of code, I do not want the listing-counter to increase. The caption should always state the same ("Listing 42: Caption")

I managed to solve point (1) by using the same caption/label for all listings. But how can I ensure that the captions do not increase the listing-counter? What is the usual way to interrupt a long listing with descriptions?

**Working example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[final]{listings}

\lstset{
    captionpos=b,
    extendedchars=true,
    numberbychapter=false,
    caption=\lstname,
    numbers=none,    
    basicstyle={\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont\footnotesize},    
    breaklines,
    breakatwhitespace,
    breakautoindent,
}

\begin{document}

  Some paragraphs describing part 1

  \begin{lstlisting}[name={Caption},label={list:Label}]
  Code Part 1
  \end{lstlisting}

  Some paragraphs describing part 2

  \begin{lstlisting}[name={Caption}]
  Code Part 2
  \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't use the caption key, so where is the problem? (But don't use the same label more than one).

Comment: The caption is automatically added and uses the value of `name`. It shows `Code 1: Caption` and `Code 2: Caption`. The only thing I want to change is, that both captions use the same counter and show `Code 1: Caption`.

Comment: You didn't get the hint: Don't show only snippets. Make a real, complete example.

Comment: I know that you can manually set the counter of enumerations with `\setcounter{enumi}{4}`, but I would need it for listing captions. And instead of setting an absolute value, I want to reduce it by 1.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The problem with the working example is, that I need to use a custom document class from my university. And I'm not good enough in LaTeX to know which parts are responsible for which effects. Unfortunately, this makes it really difficult to post questions and - of course - provide answers. I'll give it a try anyways

Comment: Turned out that `lstset` was responsible for automatically producing captions. I added a working example.

Comment: I know what you want. But I don't want to spent my time to build a test document -- even more if vital information about your setup is unknown. So if you don't provide it I won't try to find a solution. Beside this I think that someone writing an article about a long javascript listing should have enough knowledge to learn a few latex basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an empty caption and then the real caption with the title key:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[final]{listings}

    \lstset{
        captionpos=b,
        extendedchars=true,
        numberbychapter=false,
        caption=\lstname,
        numbers=none,
        basicstyle={\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont\footnotesize},
        breaklines,
        breakatwhitespace,
        breakautoindent,
    }

    \begin{document}

      Some paragraphs describing part 1

      \begin{lstlisting}[name={Caption},label={list:Label}]
      Code Part 1
      \end{lstlisting}

      Some paragraphs describing part 2

      \begin{lstlisting}[name={Caption},caption={},title={\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting: Blub (continued)}]
      Code Part 2
      \end{lstlisting}

    \end{document}
```

[image]